# deprecated warning with TBS 3.14.0 on PHP 8.2

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm getting errors like these:

```
 Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTinyButStrong::$_UserFctLst is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 738

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTbsLocator::$Ope is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 1591

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTbsLocator::$PosNext is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 1929

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTbsLocator::$Ope is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 1591

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTbsLocator::$PosNext is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 1929

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property clsTbsLocator::$PrmIf is deprecated in /home/b/s/ejEfbT2v/ftp_bswkdk/b2b/tbs/tbs_class.php on line 4659
```

Is running PHP 8.2 and TBS 3.14.0. Was running version 8.1 on an older server with no problems and no warnings. Is this only due to PHP 8.2 or can I do something about it?

Regards

Tried to look at the code, but this is not a valid solution with me editing the TBS library.

Comment: Did you take any steps to research the problem in other sources? I find that I get an understanding of the bigger picture when I do, even if those resources don't have the precise answer I need.

Answer (score 0):

Those error messages comes from PHP 8.2 and are fixed with TBS version 3.15.0.

Downloadable on [GitHub](https://github.com/Skrol29/tinybutstrong) or at the [TBS web site](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/download.php).

You will also need to update OpenTBS to version 1.11.1.

Comment: It works, thanks. Unfornately, I thought it did not work, but someone deleted my update and caused me a headache.